# Monotonically increasing maximum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

Let a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be the convex combination of two matrices as $A = qB + (1-q)C$.  Define $B$ as unit anti-diagonal.  Define $C_{i,j} = \delta_{i,i+1}$.  Consider $A$ for $n=6$, for example.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0  & 1-q & 0  & 0  & 0  & q \\
0  & 0  & 1-q & 0  & q  & 0 \\
0   & 0   & 0  & 1   & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & q  & 0  & 1-q & 0 \\
0  & q  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1-q\\
q  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I would like to prove that the maximum eigenvalue $\lambda = \max \operatorname{eig}[A]$ is monotonically increasing for $0 \le q \le 1$.  Clearly $\lambda_{q=0} = 0$ and $\lambda_{q=1} = 1$.  I can see (numerically) that $\lambda$ monotonically increases as $q \to 1$, but I cannot prove this to be the case.
[image]

Comment: But doesn't this matrix have an eigenvalue 1 for the vector $(1,1,1,1,1,1)^T$?

Comment: No. Let $Av = \lambda v$. Then from the last row we would have $q v_1 = \lambda v_6$.  This is not satisfied for $q < 1$.

Comment: Do you think the characteristic polynomial is computable explicitly, or at least by an induction relation on $n$?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Perron-Frobenius theorem to show that $λ=\sup_{x\in\Delta}\mathbf 1^TAx$ where $\Delta$ is the unit simplex $\{x\in\mathbb R_+^n:\mathbf 1^Tx=1\}$. Then the convexity follows as supremum of linear functions. However, the graph does look very concave, contradicting the claim?

Comment: @LutzL, I have hopefully improved my request as what I really need to show is that the maximum eigenvalue is monotonically increasing for $q \in [0,1]$.  We can use Perron-Frobenius to show that $\lambda \ge \min_i \sum_j A_{ij} = q$.  But while the bound strictly increases with $q$ (obviously), I cannot show that $\lambda$ must strictly increase as well.

Comment: @Seub, I have not been able to find a induction relation on n for the characteristic equation that provides any insight into the solution for any q in the interval [0,1].  We can show that $\operatorname{det}[A] = (-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}q(2q-1)^{\lceil n/2-1\rceil}$ and $\operatorname{trace}[A]=0$, but I haven't been able to use these bounds on $\sum \lambda_i$ and $\prod \lambda_i$ to bound $\lambda = \max \lambda_i$.

Comment: I see. Interesting question imho.